# Why do programming languages behave this way when there is no precedence?

Tags: javascript, python, logic

I realized that in Python and Javascript when we do this kind of conditional the logic doesn't make much sense, because if we put console.log in each condition, we will see that it should return false != true, so we should go inside the if and print the message "Is true" in the terminal, but I would like to understand why this code is printing the log of the else?

```js
const num = 7;

if (num >= 5 !== num == 5) {
  console.log("Is true");
} else {
  console.log("Is false");
}
```

I know it should take precedence in this code, but I got very confused when I put logs printing separately each condition, for example:

```js
const num = 7;
console.log(num >= 5); // true
console.log(num == 5); // false
```

true != false - should be true and enter if

```js
const num = 7;
console.log(num >= 5 !== num == 5); // false ???
```

Can someone help me with this question?

Comment: What do you mean by "when there is no precedence"? All operators have precedence.

Comment: In addition to ^^^ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `!==` has the *same* precedence as `==`, and they're left-associative. So it's equivalent to

```js
const num = 7;

console.log(((num >= 5) !== num) == 5);
```

`num >= 5` is `true`.

`true !== num` is `true`.

`true == 5` is `false`

Answer (score 0):

The code evaluates
`console.log(num >= 5 !== num == 5)`
(with `(num >= 5)` as `true`) so `true !== 5` , which is `true`.
Then, `true == 5` is `false`

It evaluates it just like math parses operations with adding and subtracting: by going in order. Precedence between == and !== is the same. If you put in parentheses, it will evaluate them in a different order.

Confirmed with python

```
>>> num=7
>>> print(num >= 5 != num == 5)
False
```

The implied alternate version does as you might expect

```
>>> num=7
>>> print(((num >= 5) != num) == 5)
False
```

This version in not equivalent!!!

```
>>> num=7
>>> print((num >= 5) != (num == 5))
True
```